# Calender control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I am writing a website in asp.net and looking for a control in which I can show a simple but very good looking calender.
The calender shoud show different events with a timestamp on it and additional informations (e.g.: 20 persons registered).
On a click on the event it should show the details.
All this must be read out of a database.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look to the jquery ui date picker http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Think what happens to the display if there are 10 events on a particular day? Calendar are date pickers, not event display controls ;-)

Comment: oups, oh yeah you are right. Forget this

Comment: Its only up to 2 entrys given on each day.

Comment: Is there any problem writing your own calendar control? It's really not that hard, especially when you describe it as `simple`...

Comment: Then you should be good. I'd follow Walther's advice and create a custom calendar.

Answer (score 0):

The Telerik RadScheduler comes to mind, but is paid: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

For free there is FullCalendar for JQuery: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Answer (score 0):

DHTMLX Scheduler .NET is also an option. Check this demo, it looks good http://scheduler-net.com/demo.aspx